# Why deploy a contract again to get its address and abi?

Tags: contract-development, javascript

I have a deploy script for my contract however, I also want to get the contract address and abi programmatically so I'm doing it like so:

First I run the deploy script that deploys my contracts.

Then I update-front-end.js which puts the address and abi into a file like so:

```
async function updateAbi() {
  const contract = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyContract")
  fs.writeFileSync(FRONT_END_ABI_FILE, contract.interface.format(ethers.utils.FormatTypes.json))
}

async function updateContractAddressess() {
  const contract = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyContract")
  MyContractContract = await contract.deploy()

  const currentAddresses = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(FRONT_END_ADDRESSES_FILE, "utf8"))
  const chainId = network.config.chainId.toString()
  currentAddresses[chainId] = [MyContractContract.address]

  fs.writeFileSync(FRONT_END_ADDRESSES_FILE, JSON.stringify(currentAddresses))
}
```

My question is why is it necessary to deploy it again to get the address and abi?
Is it a good practice?

Comment: What kind of smart contract is it? and why you're deploying it again?

Comment: Okay, the reason I want the contract address / abi is to execute any function on my website (front-end) for example a getBalanceOf(address) function. I don't think it matters what kind of smart contract it is but mine is an ERC20 token.
I'm deploying it twice to get the abi and address programmatically, because I believe that when I deploy again, the address is the same (and the abi is the same). If I didn't deploy it twice, how would I get the address and abi dynamically, meaning if I change the contract and compile I don't need to manually change the abi for example. That's the main goal.